# Form alignment with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> How do I create form with following format[Shown in Picture]- Irrespective of the size
>   of name variable(Name, Mobile,Gender,Age) , all the value receiving
>   blocks are of same size, aligned one below another.
>
> My approach is that two div would be there one with all names and
>   other with all blocks.
>   But it's weird I haven't done anything like
>   this before.
>
> And Can It be done by Bootstrap? I would prefer that.

[image: Form]

Comment: Show your code where you are try ?

Comment: You can quite easily do this using tables, instead of div.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Rizwan Ali</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Your Required Form with bootstrap</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Mobile:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter 10 digits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Alternate Mobile:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Gender:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control">
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Age:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="In Years">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Date of Dog Bite:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="date" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Credit Card Number:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="date" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i did it with *bootstrap*, **NOTE:** validation is not there you can do it at your own if that is required too then tell in comment
check this by clicking run button above

Comment: How do we change label(Name, Gender,Age etc.) alignment of all fields at once. In your code the alignment is to the right while I was trying to do it to left side(As shown in image).

Comment: you can place lables and input controls into different col-md-* as per your requirment